# java ZipOutputStream doesn't compress

Tags: java, io, zip

I am trying to output data through ZipOutputStream, but the resulting file is not compressed. This is under Windows 7. Here is an example:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.zip.*;

public class Testy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] data = new byte[100];
        Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        try {
            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(
                    Paths.get("record.zip"), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND), 200000);
            ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(out);
            zout.setLevel(4);

            zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("record.dat"));
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                rnd.nextBytes(data);
                zout.write(data, 0, data.length);
                Thread.sleep(1L);
            }
            zout.closeEntry();
            zout.finish();
            zout.close();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
}
```

thanks for any help

Comment: How do you it doesn't compress, have you tried writing the content to an uncompressed file as well?

Comment: @MadProgrammer As a result I've got uncompressed zip file with data inside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compression works by encoding repeated and predictable patterns in the input with shorter byte sequences. A *completely random* input, like you have here, has no predictable patterns, and cannot be compressed. The same would happen if you compressed a file that had already been compressed.

Try generating random upper case characters, random English words, or a random DNA sequence (letters A C T G) instead of random bytes, and you will see how well they are compressed.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but why not nitpick just a little bit... the pseudorandom sequence which OP is using is incredibly compressible: it is fully specified just by the single `long` seed :)

Comment: Haha, true, the entire file could be compressed to exactly 48 bits :)